# Algorithm for converting Category Tree to Flat List

Tags: javascript, c++, algorithm, logic

I am trying to convert a Categories Tree to a flat list.

In the Categories any category can have n levels of subcategories.

```
For Ex.:

Category1
-SubCategory1
-SubCategory2
--SubCategor1
---SubCategory1
---SubCategory2
----SubCategory1
----SubCategory2
---SubCategory3
--SubCategory2
-SubCategory3

Category2
-SubCategory1
--SubCategory1
---SubCategory1
----SubCategory1
---SubCategory3
-SubCategory3

...etc and so on.
```

Language is not a barrier I am just trying to formulate loops/nested loops to create this logic to convert it into a flattened list.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entry to your flat List will be a node of your Tree as that is visited according to Depth First Search. For more information please [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search)

Edit:
The original post was edited a couple of times. Initially, it looked like the OP was after a flat list as that would be the output of BFS but after a later edit it looked like the OP was after a flat list as that would be the output of DFS. The more general case then would be that "Each entry to the flat list will be a node of the Tree as that is visited by some traversal function (such as BFS or DFS)."

Comment: Thanks DFS seems like what I want to do. but it looks like it will only work for binary tree structure but I the looking for a solution when a tree can have n branches at any stage.

Comment: DFS and BFS will traverse trees with nodes having any number of branches. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode please notice the "for all edges e in G" part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by a flat list, but you can use a stack (implementation wise, it can be STL vector) to store the current progress while recursively visiting the sub categories.

"The current progress" that I mentioned above should store which subcategory that you are currently visiting, so that you can continue to visit other subcategory when you return.

If you can formulate a recursive algorithm, you can rewrite it in this form.

Comment: Thank you, by flat list I meant a plain list

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make this using recursion + [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) function.

Comment: Recursion may result in stack overflow when the number of level is too many. It is acceptable when the number of levels is known.